# How to paralellize a divide and conquer algorithm in Clojure

Tags: concurrency, clojure, divide-and-conquer

First of all say I have a problem, calculating 1 Billion digits of Pi, calculating the factorial of a large number, or performing mergesort over a large list. I would like to divide the problem into smaller tasks and execute each of the tasks concurrently and combine the results. First of all what is the name of this type of concurrency and how would you do it in Clojure?

Comment: I have not looked at them in any depth, but perhaps this is a job for "Clojure Reducers" which use fork-join parallelism under the hood.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15160/calculating-a-factorial-with-parallel-sub-computations-using-pmap-pvalues-and-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current Clojure 1.4, you could accomplish this using maybe [`pmap`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/pmap), [`pcalls`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/pcalls), or [`pvalues`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/pvalues). The `pmap` function is a parallel version of `map`, whereas `pcalls` and `pvalues` don't really have analogous non-parallel versions (although, I suppose `list` is a "non-parallel version" of `pvalues`).

However, for the problems you describe, it sounds like you would want to use a parallel version of `reduce`. There is an old one from Clojure 1.2 ( [see here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.datalog.util/preduce)), which I've never used, so I'm not able to speak about its utility.

Coming with Clojure 1.5 will be this new "reducers" library, which Rich Hickey blogs about [here](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html). Here, `fold` seems to be a parallel version of `reduce`.